# delete all users with specific domain prefix

Tags: list, powershell, user-information-list

I need to delete all the Users from the hidden List `_catalog/users` where user's domain is `NorthP` so sample user would be `NorthP\johnd`. What am I missing from the following PS code?

```
ADD-PSSNAPIN MICROSOFT.SHAREPOINT.POWERSHELL -EA CONTINUE
$SITE = GET-SPSITE "HTTP://siteurl/site"
$WEB = $SITE.ROOTWEB
$LIST = $WEB.LISTS["USER INFORMATION LIST"]

$I = $LIST.ITEMS | WHERE {$_["ACCOUNT"] -Like '*NorthP\*'}
$I.DELETE()
$WEB.DISPOSE()
$SITE.DISPOSE()
```

Comment: Taking a quick look, pretty sure you need to do a foreach to cycle through the items before deleting..

Comment: check this one, http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/delete-users-clean-up-user-information-list.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea continue
$site = get-spsite "http://siteurl/site"
$web = $site.rootweb
$list = $web.lists["user information list"]

$items = $list.items | where-object {$_["Account"] -like '*northp*'}

$listItemsTotal = $items.Count;
for($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
    $item = $list.GetItemById($items[$x].Id)
    remove-spuser $items[$x]["Account"] -web $web -confirm:$False
}

$web.dispose()
$site.dispose()
```

Comment: there is something wrong with this where {$_["account"] -like '*northp\*' because the count is zero. but without this filter the count is 6624. i verified via UI that there are users with northP domain.

Comment: The count is still zero. what is happening?

Comment: Amal: you are good. I would not have thought of that. It's case sensitive. Thank you Amal.

Comment: @MileyJordan You are welcome!. I also updated answer.

Comment: $items[$x].Delete() is throwing an error. delete with 0 argument....

Comment: it did not delete the record.

Comment: It prints ID on the screen. It's giving me this error.  [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Delete'.

Comment: I think we both updated at the same time. I added this remove-spuser $Items[$x]["Account"] -web $web -confirm:$True and now it's working. Thanks for all your help.